# PHP cURL getting encoded data

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler

I have downloaded page header and compressed body in one string by using cURL, problem is that I don't know how to split them from each other and how to decompress body?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try setting the [`CURLOPT_ENCODING`](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) cURL option before fetching the page, like so:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
// supported encodings: "identity", "deflate", and "gzip"
// or empty string, "", sending all supported encoding types
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

this should send the `Accept-Encoding` header and automatically decode the response.